# Is there a way around "deduced conflicting types for parameter in template instantiation" for types that convert to each other?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I was playing around with having my own wrapper around iterator that is templated on iterator type. 
It works ok, but problems arise when I try to use it in algorithm where I mix my iterator and vector iterator.

```
vector<int> vi{1,2,3,4,5};                                                 
auto my_it2 = my_find(vi,2);
cout << *my_it2;// works fine
// but this does not:
vector<int> vi2 (vi.begin(), /*(std::vector<int>::iterator)*/my_it2);
```

> include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:392:9: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for
>   parameter '_InputIterator'

my_it struct has an operator for conversion to normal iterator(that is why if you uncomment "cast" it works, but it is ugly.
Is there a way to go around this?
I doubt it since even std::max does not work for short and int, but better check on SO. :)

Comment: It would help if we know the type that `my_find()` returns. It may not be returning an iterator that is compatible with the `InputIterator` concept.

Comment: It is just a wrapper for find that returns my_iter of find result, I dont think it matters, since like I said template instantiation fails because he expects both iterators to be of the same type. If it failed deep in the call and said cant ++ something then I guess problem could be with the struct not satisfying the iterator concept.

Comment: The type your function returns is the *only* thing that matters. The vector constructor expects two iterators of exactly the same type. If the `my_find` function is not returning exactly the same iterator type as `.begin()`, then this is what you should expect to happen.

Comment: It does not return the same type, and that is the cause of compile error. Question is about is there a way around this beside ugly (std::vector<int>::iterator) my_it2

Comment: Consider exposing a member function in your iterator type that returns the normal container iterator, like `reverse_iterator`'s `base()` member.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can, the constructor you call from std::vector is a function template, and no implicit type conversion is allowed during template parameter deduction. So you have to make sure they are the same type of iterators.

You can create a non-member and non-template function (or a specification of template function for vector::iterator and your iterator) to construct a vector by taking different iterators, basically hide the "ugly" bit in a function.